# Radix sort using array of linked list as bin in C

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, linked-list, radix-sort

I am trying to implement radix sort in C using an array of linked lists as a bin for storing the elements according to their place value. But the heads of the linked lists are always staying `NULL`. And if I try to access them directly without the temp variable, it is giving segmentation fault. Please help.
Thank you in advance.

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

// array of linked list
struct node *radix[10];

// initializing all list head with null
void init() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        radix[i] = NULL;
    }
}

// fucntion for making a node
struct node *make_new_node(int data) {
    struct node *new_node = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node->next = NULL;
    new_node->data = data;
    return new_node;
}

// function for getting the maximum digit
int get_max_digit(int *arr, int n) {
    int i, max = arr[0], count = 0;
    // This loop is for finding the maximum number
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > max) {
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }
    // This loop is for getting the total number digits of the maximum number
    while (max != 0) {
        max /= 10;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

// function for inserting the digit in the last node
void insert_into_bin(int data, int rad) {
    struct node *new_node = make_new_node(data);
    struct node *temp = radix[rad];
    if (temp == NULL) {
        temp = new_node;
    } else {
        while (temp->next!=NULL) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = new_node;
    }
}

// function for radix sort
void radix_sort(int *arr, int n) {
    int i, j = 0, k, pass, digit, div = 1;
    pass = get_max_digit(arr, n);
    
    for (i = 1; i <= pass; i++) {
        printf("\ndiv = %d\n\n", div);
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            // getting the corresponding digit
            digit = (arr[j] / div) % 10;
            
            // inserting into the bin
            insert_into_bin(arr[j], digit);
        }
        // now multiplying div with 10 and storing it in div
        div *= 10;
        // Now the list is sorted in the array of linked list
        // Time to retrieve them
        j = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
            struct node *temp = radix[i];
            while (temp != NULL) {
                arr[j++] = temp->data;
            }
        }
        init();
    }
}

// function for printing the array
void display(int *arr, int n) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

// driver function
int main() {
    // calling the init function
    init();
    int arr[6] = { 655, 12, 7845, 2, 45, 45122 };
    radix_sort(arr, 6);
    display(arr, 6);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple problems:

- `insert_into_bin` never stores the pointer to the new node into `radix[rad]` in case it is a null pointer.
- the copying loop in `radix_sort()` uses `radix[i]` instead of `radix[k]` and never sets `temp = temp->next;`
- you never free the lists

Here is a modified version:

```
// function for inserting the digit in the last node
void insert_into_bin(int data, int rad) {
    struct node *new_node = make_new_node(data);
    struct node *temp = radix[rad];
    if (temp == NULL) {
        radix[rad] = new_node;
    } else {
        while (temp->next != NULL) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = new_node;
    }
}

// function for radix sort
void radix_sort(int *arr, int n) {
    int i, j = 0, k, pass, digit, div = 1;
    pass = get_max_digit(arr, n);

    for (i = 1; i <= pass; i++) {
        printf("\ndiv = %d\n\n", div);
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            // getting the corresponding digit
            digit = (arr[j] / div) % 10;

            // inserting into the bin
            insert_into_bin(arr[j], digit);
        }
        // now multiplying div with 10 and storing it in div
        div *= 10;
        // Now the list is sorted in the array of linked list
        // Time to retrieve them
        j = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
            struct node *temp = radix[k];
            radix[k] = NULL;
            while (temp != NULL) {
                struct node *next = temp->next;
                arr[j++] = temp->data;
                free(temp);
                temp = next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Studying your approach, I'm afraid the complexity is far above the expected **O(n)** or more precisely **O(n.log(max_value))**. Here are some sources of concern:

- allocating and freeing a list element for each entry in the array for each pass is very costly and may add a non linear complexity factor.
- searching for the last list element to append the element is a linear search, which translates into quadratic complexity for the iterated operation.

Here is an instrumented version to illustrate this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define DIVISOR  10

// function for radix sort
void radix_sort(int *arr, int n) {
    int i, j, k, div, max;
    struct node {
        int data;
        struct node *next;
    } *radix[DIVISOR];

    if (n < 2)
        return;

    for (i = 0; i < DIVISOR; i++)
        radix[i] = NULL;

    // This loop is for finding the maximum number
    max = arr[0];
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > max) {
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }

    div = 1;
    while (max > 0) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            // allocate a new node
            struct node *new_node = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            struct node *temp;
            new_node->next = NULL;
            new_node->data = arr[j];

            // getting the corresponding digit
            int digit = (arr[j] / div) % DIVISOR;

            // inserting into the bin
            temp = radix[digit];
            if (temp == NULL) {
                radix[digit] = new_node;
            } else {
                while (temp->next != NULL) {
                    temp = temp->next;
                }
                temp->next = new_node;
            }
        }
        // now multiplying div with 10 and storing it in div
        div *= DIVISOR;
        max /= DIVISOR;
        // Now the list is sorted in the array of linked list
        // Time to retrieve them
        j = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < DIVISOR; k++) {
            struct node *temp = radix[k];
            radix[k] = NULL;
            while (temp != NULL) {
                struct node *next = temp->next;
                arr[j++] = temp->data;
                free(temp);
                temp = next;
            }
        }
    }
}

// driver function
int main() {
    double last_clock = 0;
    for (int p = 0; p < 28; p++) {
        int n = 1 << p;
        int *arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * n);
        unsigned long long sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[i] = rand() % n;
            sum1 += arr[i];
        }
        clock_t t = -clock();
        radix_sort(arr, n);
        t += clock();
        sum2 = arr[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            sum2 += arr[i];
            if (arr[i-1] > arr[i]) {
                printf("%d: out of order at %d\n", n, i);
                return 1;
            }
        }
        if (sum1 != sum2) {
            printf("%d: checksum mismatch: %llu != %llu\n", n, sum1, sum2);
            return 1;
        }
        printf("%d: %.3fms ratio=%.2f\n",
               n, t * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC,
               last_clock > 0 ? t / last_clock : 0);
        if (t > 7 * CLOCKS_PER_SEC)
            break;
        last_clock = t;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output clearly shows quadratic time complexity:

```
1: 0.002ms ratio=0.00
2: 0.007ms ratio=3.50
4: 0.001ms ratio=0.14
8: 0.002ms ratio=2.00
16: 0.006ms ratio=3.00
32: 0.010ms ratio=1.67
64: 0.021ms ratio=2.10
128: 0.067ms ratio=3.19
256: 0.134ms ratio=2.00
512: 0.314ms ratio=2.34
1024: 1.527ms ratio=4.86
2048: 3.508ms ratio=2.30
4096: 12.916ms ratio=3.68
8192: 56.545ms ratio=4.38
16384: 399.561ms ratio=7.07
32768: 1793.814ms ratio=4.49
65536: 7419.397ms ratio=4.14
```

You can address the bottleneck using a separate array for the list heads and tails:

```
#define DIVISOR  10

// function for radix sort
void radix_sort(int *arr, int n) {
    int i, j, k, div, max;
    struct node {
        int data;
        struct node *next;
    } *radix[DIVISOR], *tail[DIVISOR];

    if (n < 2)
        return;

    for (i = 0; i < DIVISOR; i++)
        tail[i] = radix[i] = NULL;

    // This loop is for finding the maximum number
    max = arr[0];
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > max) {
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }

    div = 1;
    while (max > 0) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            // allocate a new node
            struct node *new_node = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            new_node->next = NULL;
            new_node->data = arr[j];

            // getting the corresponding digit
            int digit = (arr[j] / div) % DIVISOR;

            // inserting into the bin
            if (radix[digit] == NULL) {
                tail[digit] = radix[digit] = new_node;
            } else {
                tail[digit] = tail[digit]->next = new_node;
            }
        }
        // now multiplying div with 10 and storing it in div
        div *= DIVISOR;
        max /= DIVISOR;
        // Now the list is sorted in the array of linked list
        // Time to retrieve them
        j = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < DIVISOR; k++) {
            struct node *temp = radix[k];
            tail[k] = radix[k] = NULL;
            while (temp != NULL) {
                struct node *next = temp->next;
                arr[j++] = temp->data;
                free(temp);
                temp = next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This fixes the problem and allows for much larger arrays to be sorted quickly:

```
1: 0.003ms ratio=0.00
2: 0.007ms ratio=2.33
4: 0.001ms ratio=0.14
8: 0.002ms ratio=2.00
16: 0.005ms ratio=2.50
32: 0.010ms ratio=2.00
64: 0.018ms ratio=1.80
128: 0.054ms ratio=3.00
256: 0.150ms ratio=2.78
512: 0.236ms ratio=1.57
1024: 0.535ms ratio=2.27
2048: 1.469ms ratio=2.75
4096: 2.397ms ratio=1.63
8192: 4.536ms ratio=1.89
16384: 11.487ms ratio=2.53
32768: 26.473ms ratio=2.30
65536: 58.251ms ratio=2.20
131072: 120.385ms ratio=2.07
262144: 247.752ms ratio=2.06
524288: 535.602ms ratio=2.16
1048576: 1243.067ms ratio=2.32
2097152: 2651.775ms ratio=2.13
4194304: 5345.552ms ratio=2.02
8388608: 10962.960ms ratio=2.05
```

The `malloc` overhead can be addressed by allocating 2 ancillary arrays:

- one to copy the values
- one to store the next pointers.

These arrays are allocated once, used for every pass and freed at the end.

Here is the modified `radix_sort()` function:

```
#define DIVISOR  10

// function for radix sort
int radix_sort(int *arr, int n) {
    int i, j, k, div, max;
    int radix[DIVISOR], tail[DIVISOR];
    int *data;
    int *next;

    if (n < 2)
        return 0;

    data = malloc(sizeof(*data) * n);
    if (data == NULL)
        return -1;
    next = malloc(sizeof(*next) * (n + 1));
    if (next == NULL) {
        free(data);
        return -1;
    }
    for (k = 0; k < DIVISOR; k++)
        tail[k] = radix[k] = n;

    // This loop is for finding the maximum number
    max = arr[0];
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > max) {
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }

    div = 1;
    while (max > 0) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            data[j] = arr[j];
            // getting the corresponding digit
            int digit = (arr[j] / div) % DIVISOR;

            // inserting into the bin
            if (radix[digit] == n) {
                tail[digit] = radix[digit] = j;
            } else {
                tail[digit] = next[tail[digit]] = j;
            }
        }
        // now multiplying div with 10 and storing it in div
        div *= DIVISOR;
        max /= DIVISOR;
        // Now the list is sorted in the array of linked list
        // Time to retrieve them
        j = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < DIVISOR; k++) {
            int temp = radix[k];
            tail[k] = radix[k] = next[tail[k]] = n;
            while (temp != n) {
                arr[j++] = data[temp];
                temp = next[temp];
            }
        }
    }
    free(data);
    free(next);
    return 0;
}
```

And the timings show a performance improvement of **12x** with the same quasi-linear complexity:

```
1: 0.002ms ratio=0.00
2: 0.016ms ratio=8.00
4: 0.001ms ratio=0.06
8: 0.002ms ratio=2.00
16: 0.003ms ratio=1.50
32: 0.003ms ratio=1.00
64: 0.004ms ratio=1.33
128: 0.010ms ratio=2.50
256: 0.010ms ratio=1.00
512: 0.022ms ratio=2.20
1024: 0.055ms ratio=2.50
2048: 0.138ms ratio=2.51
4096: 0.215ms ratio=1.56
8192: 0.457ms ratio=2.13
16384: 1.084ms ratio=2.37
32768: 1.913ms ratio=1.76
65536: 3.426ms ratio=1.79
131072: 8.062ms ratio=2.35
262144: 26.584ms ratio=3.30
524288: 58.333ms ratio=2.19
1048576: 104.538ms ratio=1.79
2097152: 197.730ms ratio=1.89
4194304: 390.818ms ratio=1.98
8388608: 810.972ms ratio=2.08
16777216: 2057.180ms ratio=2.54
33554432: 3611.793ms ratio=1.76
67108864: 7858.513ms ratio=2.18
```

Further improvements can be obtained by avoiding divisions:

- using powers of 2 for `DIVISOR` and shift and mask to extract the digits
- using separate destination indexes instead of a linked list of entries for the same digit.

Here is an illustration, increasing `DIVISOR` to 64, using half the memory of the previous version:

```
#define SHIFT    6
#define MASK     ((1 << SHIFT) - 1)
#define DIVISOR  (1 << SHIFT)

// function for radix sort
int radix_sort(int *arr, int n) {
    int i, j, k, shift, max;
    int count[DIVISOR], index[DIVISOR];
    int *data;

    if (n < 2)
        return 0;

    data = malloc(sizeof(*data) * n);
    if (data == NULL)
        return -1;

    // This loop is for finding the maximum number
    max = arr[0];
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > max) {
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }

    shift = 0;
    while (max > 0) {
        for (k = 0; k < DIVISOR; k++)
            count[k] = 0;

        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            // copy the value
            data[j] = arr[j];
            // getting the corresponding digit
            int digit = (data[j] >> shift) & MASK;
            // increase this digit's count
            count[digit] += 1;
        }
        // compute the starting indexes
        index[0] = 0;
        for (k = 1; k < DIVISOR; k++) {
            index[k] = index[k - 1] + count[k - 1];
        }
        // dispatch the values in the order of their current digit
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            int val = data[j];
            // getting the corresponding digit
            int digit = (val >> shift) & MASK;
            arr[index[digit]++] = val;
        }
        // update shift and max
        shift += SHIFT;
        max >>= SHIFT;
    }
    free(data);
    return 0;
}
```

Output shows another significant improvement (**7x** faster):

```
1: 0.002ms ratio=0.00
2: 0.027ms ratio=13.50
4: 0.002ms ratio=0.07
8: 0.003ms ratio=1.50
16: 0.003ms ratio=1.00
32: 0.002ms ratio=0.67
64: 0.002ms ratio=1.00
128: 0.003ms ratio=1.50
256: 0.004ms ratio=1.33
512: 0.010ms ratio=2.50
1024: 0.013ms ratio=1.30
2048: 0.022ms ratio=1.69
4096: 0.046ms ratio=2.09
8192: 0.114ms ratio=2.48
16384: 0.221ms ratio=1.94
32768: 0.366ms ratio=1.66
65536: 0.864ms ratio=2.36
131072: 1.184ms ratio=1.37
262144: 2.884ms ratio=2.44
524288: 12.569ms ratio=4.36
1048576: 21.896ms ratio=1.74
2097152: 34.809ms ratio=1.59
4194304: 61.134ms ratio=1.76
8388608: 105.110ms ratio=1.72
16777216: 212.954ms ratio=2.03
33554432: 548.368ms ratio=2.58
67108864: 1025.203ms ratio=1.87
134217728: 2340.717ms ratio=2.28
```

There is always room for improvement: copying the data during the digit count phase can be omitted if the dispatch phases alternate between the `data` and `arr` arrays. I tried this but it does not seem to have much effect at all, actually slowing down in many cases.

Always benchmark supposed improvements and make sure they still produce the correct result: correctness always beats performance.

Talking about correctness, it is important to note that all of the above implementations can only handle positive numbers. To handle the full range of type `int`, one needs to use type `unsigned` and sort the values based on their difference from the minimum value:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SHIFT    8
#define MASK     ((1 << SHIFT) - 1)
#define DIVISOR  (1 << SHIFT)

// function for radix sort
int radix_sort(int *arr, int n) {
    int min, max;
    unsigned k, shift, range;
    int j;
    int count[DIVISOR], index[DIVISOR];
    unsigned *data, *src, *dst, *temp;

    if (n < 2)
        return 0;

    data = malloc(sizeof(*data) * n);
    if (data == NULL)
        return -1;

    src = (unsigned *)arr;
    dst = data;

    // This loop is for finding the minimum and maximum numbers
    min = max = src[0];
    for (j = 1; j < n; j++) {
        int val = arr[j];
        if (min > val) min = val;
        if (max < val) max = val;
    }
    range = (unsigned)max - (unsigned)min;

    for (shift = 0; range > 0; shift += SHIFT, range >>= SHIFT) {
        for (k = 0; k < DIVISOR; k++)
            count[k] = 0;

        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            // getting the corresponding digit
            unsigned val = src[j] - (unsigned)min;
            unsigned digit = (val >> shift) & MASK;
            // increase this digit's count
            count[digit] += 1;
        }
        // check for trivial case
        for (k = 0; count[k] == 0; k++) {
            index[k] = 0;
        }
        if (count[k] == n) {
            // all digits are identical
            continue;
        }
        // compute the remaining starting indexes
        index[k] = 0;
        for (k += 1; k < DIVISOR; k++) {
            index[k] = index[k - 1] + count[k - 1];
        }
        // dispatch the values in the order of their current digit
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            unsigned val = src[j] - (unsigned)min;
            // getting the corresponding digit
            unsigned digit = (val >> shift) & MASK;
            dst[index[digit]++] = src[j];
        }
        // swap source and destination arrays
        temp = src;
        src = dst;
        dst = temp;
    }
    if (src == data) {
        // copy data back to the original array
        memcpy(arr, data, sizeof(*arr) * n);
    }
    free(data);
    return 0;
}

// driver function
int main() {
    double last_clock = 0;
    for (int p = 0; p < 28; p++) {
        int n = 1 << p;
        int *arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * n);
        unsigned long long sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            // mix positive and negative values
            int v = rand();
            int val = (v >> 1) % n;
            arr[i] = (v & 1) ? -val : val;
            sum1 += arr[i];
        }
        clock_t t = -clock();
        radix_sort(arr, n);
        t += clock();
        sum2 = arr[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            sum2 += arr[i];
            if (arr[i-1] > arr[i]) {
                printf("%d: out of order at %d\n", n, i);
                return 1;
            }
        }
        if (sum1 != sum2) {
            printf("%d: checksum mismatch: %llu != %llu\n", n, sum1, sum2);
            return 1;
        }
        printf("%d: %.3fms ratio=%.2f\n",
               n, t * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC,
               last_clock > 0 ? t / last_clock : 0);
        if (t > 7 * CLOCKS_PER_SEC)
            break;
        last_clock = t;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This small change has little impact on the overall performance but improves correctness:

```
1: 0.002ms ratio=0.00
2: 0.010ms ratio=5.00
4: 0.018ms ratio=1.80
8: 0.002ms ratio=0.11
16: 0.002ms ratio=1.00
32: 0.001ms ratio=0.50
64: 0.001ms ratio=1.00
128: 0.002ms ratio=2.00
256: 0.006ms ratio=3.00
512: 0.010ms ratio=1.67
1024: 0.014ms ratio=1.40
2048: 0.024ms ratio=1.71
4096: 0.049ms ratio=2.04
8192: 0.095ms ratio=1.94
16384: 0.201ms ratio=2.12
32768: 0.284ms ratio=1.41
65536: 0.969ms ratio=3.41
131072: 1.496ms ratio=1.54
262144: 3.034ms ratio=2.03
524288: 14.288ms ratio=4.71
1048576: 21.479ms ratio=1.50
2097152: 34.468ms ratio=1.60
4194304: 70.317ms ratio=2.04
8388608: 117.420ms ratio=1.67
16777216: 251.831ms ratio=2.14
33554432: 522.936ms ratio=2.08
67108864: 1076.859ms ratio=2.06
134217728: 2300.456ms ratio=2.14
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a debugger and execute your code step-by-step, as @Paul R suggested.
First of all, the variable radix is an array of 10 node* elements, contiguous in memory, but without any links between them.

It is sufficent to declare the variable radix as a node*, and then link the subsequent values through the "node* next" field inside your struct. Obviusly, you will need to allocate enough memory for each node* you will use.

I'll try to give you a suggestion:

```
struct node* init() {

struct node* radix = calloc(1, sizeof(struct node*)); // Allocating space for radix variable.
radix->data = 0; // Setting default data value to 0.
radix->next = NULL; // Setting next element to NULL.

struct node* tmp = radix; //Temporary pointer to add following nodes. 

size_t size = 5; // Defining a size for the list.

for (size_t i = 1; i < size; i++)
{
    //Each node will need some space in memory. Don't forget to de-allocate memory once you don't need it anymore.
    struct node* flw = calloc(1, sizeof(struct node*)); 

    flw->data = 0; // Setting default data value to 0.
    flw->next = NULL; // Setting next element to NULL.
    tmp->next = flw; // tmp is the previous node, so we update the NEXT in order to link all the node.
    tmp = flw; //At the end, we need to update flw to the current item, that in the next iteration will become the previous.
}

return radix; //returning the head of the list
}
```

Keep in mind that now, in order to access to the element in the list, you will not use the [] operator, but the "next" variable stored in each node.